# Loadbalance a bunch of Squid servers

Tags: load-balancing, squid

I'm trying to load balance a network of proxy (squid) servers (currently 8 nodes) efficiently.

I'm currently balancing over a network wide proxy autoconfig but that seems to not work properly. Some servers do get a horrible amount of load, some are just sitting there and waiting for requests.

What's an efficient way to balance these (without changing too much on the client side)? Is it possible to do some kind of request delegating instead of just forwarding:

```
Client -> Balancer -> ProxyX | ProxyX -> Client
```

I'd like to avoid traffic bottlenecks:

```
Client -> Balancer -> ProxyX | ProxyX -> Balancer -> Client
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not tell us about the type/name of your load balancer. You can try [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/). It does a good job in distributing the load among servers and it can perform checks to maintain list of alive servers. Its powerful ACL is very flexible and it supports different load balancing algorithms. Normally, it does not require any change in the client side.

Comment: That's because I'm not using a load balancer right now. The balancing is currently handled on the clientside using a proxy autoconfig script. On the first check, haproxy seems to be perfect. Gonna try that out. Thank you!